# Android asmack vcard classcastException while calling vcard.load(conn)

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack, vcf-vcard

**I am using asmack-android-8-4.0.5.jar from http://asmack.freakempire.de/4.0.5/** **I am able to connect and login successfully, but when i try to load my own vcard it throws classcastexception at vcard.doload method. please help anybody.Below is the full code that i am using.**

```
private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
        configure(new ProviderManager());
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                "my host here", 5222, "xmpp.jp");
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
        ProviderManager.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp",
                new VCardProvider());
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
        try {
            connection.connect();
            System.out.println("sanidhya09 connected");

            try {
                connection.login("sanidhya09", "*****");
                System.out.println("sanidhya09 logged in ");
            } catch (SaslException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("sanidhya09 Failed to connect to "
                    + "xmpp.jp");
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        Presence pres = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);

        try {
            connection.sendPacket(pres);
        } catch (NotConnectedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        VCard vCard = new VCard();
        try {
            ProviderManager.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp",
                    new VCardProvider());
            System.out.println("sanidhya09 vcard trying");
            vCard.load(connection);
            System.out.println("sanidhya09 vcard loaded");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils$2 cannot be cast to org.jivesoftware.smackx.vcardtemp.packet.VCard
11-05 16:09:57.379: W/System.err(26675):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.vcardtemp.packet.VCard.doLoad(VCard.java:560)
11-05 16:09:57.379: W/System.err(26675):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.vcardtemp.packet.VCard.load(VCard.java:542)
11-05 16:09:57.379: W/System.err(26675):    at com.sanidhya.chatdemo.MainActivity$ConnectTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:111)
11-05 16:09:57.379: W/System.err(26675):    at com.sanidhya.chatdemo.MainActivity$ConnectTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-05 16:09:57.380: W/System.err(26675):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Always include the full exception **including** their stacktrace!

Comment: hi @Flow Just now i found out that my code's vcard works fine with gtalk server but fails at vcard with xmpp.jp or jabber.se servers. can u suggest some good server that sends xml respnse in caps. or how can i fix this? note: i have build my app using asmack source.

Comment: Why does it fail? Why didn't you add the asked information?

Comment: @Flow sorry, I have added it now. Kindly scroll the code to bottom.

Comment: Did you read and follow the instructions of the aSmack README?

Comment: @Flow Thanks for reminding. I think you are going to save my life.Now I have added SmackAndroid.init(getApplicationContext()) before instatntiating ConnectionConfiguration class, but still getting the same classcastexception. I am using asmack-android-8-4.0.5.jar

Comment: @Flow I have also added dnsjava-2.1.6.jar to my libs

Comment: @Flow I am not using proguard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64313/discussion-between-sanidhya09-and-flow).

Comment: hey any luck in this ?! @flow any advice

Answer (score 2):

I got it working now. Actually their was a problem in the xml response. It did not have the avatar in it or had a malfunctioned avatar. I even had a wrong base64 while saving the avatar.

**Got it working by saving the avatars this way:**

```
    private void uploadProfilePic() {
    try {
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selected_img,128, 128,
                true);
        obj_UserInfo.setProfilePic(resized);
        String get64BaseString = get64BaseString(resized);

        VCard vCard = new VCard();

        vCard.setAvatar(get64BaseString, "image/jpeg");
        vCard.save(CGlobalVarriables.connection);
        System.out.println("image upload successfuls");
        CGlobalVarriables.obj_UserInfo.setProfilePic(resized);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Loaded theVcard by this way:**

```
private Bitmap getProfilePic() {

    VCard vCard = new VCard();
    try {
        vCard.load(CGlobalVarriables.connection);
        byte[] array = vCard.getAvatar();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0,
                array.length);

        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: will check now and get back to you

Comment: May I ask you to report you findings to the [Smack Developers](http://community.igniterealtime.org/community/developers/smack) forum? It is still unclear to me what exactly is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i face the same too i found this :

```
VCard result = (VCard) connection.createPacketCollectorAndSend(this).nextResultOrThrow();
```

change this to

```
Packet packet = connection.createPacketCollectorAndSend(this).nextResultOrThrow();
```

and print this , vcard packet returned is perfect has all N FN EMAIL TEL fields as XML tags , the class cast exception is because Vcard.java extends as IQ , IQ is a class Which extends packet

For now i am using SAXParser and xml to extract details i read from the object packet above and saving it in vcard as required , still no success but extraction is working.

Started to face issue after upgrade , will post a better solution soon , if @flow can answer or fix this that would be great

Comment: no need to change anything, asmack library is awesome. This happens while calling vcard.load(conn) when you do not have a proper vcard with avatar set on it. I would like to see how you are saving a vcard.

Comment: Used Spark(igniteRealtime) to set vCard , thanks will check by setting via asmack

Comment: But why class cast exception